# Do I need to configure SVG images showing in nginx?

Tags: nginx, static-content

I have SVG images in a folder and also a single PNG file to make sure these images are shown on the page.

My nginx config is basically this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        root www;
    }

}
```

The images are in `www/images` folder.

What I see is with the same structure in the page:

```
<img src="images/logo.svg">
<img src="images/logo.png">
```

PNG file is shown on the page just as expected, but not SVG. It shows in network tab of the browser code 200, though, but empty body.

When I try to open it directly, like `http://localhost/images/logo.svg`, it just downloads it as a file.

Do I need to add some special config to make SVG files showable on a page like PNG/JPG files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add SVG `image/svg+xml svg svgz;` to your mime types in `/etc/nginx/mime.types` and reload your Nginx.

Answer (score 7):

When Nginx doesn't recognize the mime type for `.svg` files, it serves them with content type header `content-type: text/plain` and your browser may not render them or may issue a warning to the web console.

1. Ensure that `/etc/nginx/mime.types` defines a mime type for svg images:

   ```
   types {
     ...
     image/svg+xml   svg svgz;
     ...
   }
   ```
2. Ensure that `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` includes the `mime.types` file in the http block:

   ```
   http {
     include mime.types;
     ...
   }
   ```
3. In the terminal check that your new nginx configuration has no errors:

   ```
   sudo nginx -t
   ```
4. Restart NGINX for the changes to take effect

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart nginx   // e.g.: ubuntu
   ```
5. In your browser dev tools under network headers, check that svg files are served with header `Content-Type: image/svg+xml` and possibly hard refresh your web page to update the browser cache.